Scroll-snap event fires twice on release using firefox
Assuming we scroll 3 divs in a div.
Using scroll-snap-... we can "animate" the alignment of that scroll.


div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:auto;
  display:inline-block;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.red{background:red;}
.green{background:green;}
.blue{background:blue;}
<div class=viewport onscrollend=console.log(event)>
   <div class=red>&raquo;</div>
   <div class=green>&raquo;</div>
   <div class=blue>&raquo;</div>



During release the scroll-wheel (or the finger on a mobil phone accordingly) the end-scroll-event fire twice.

It fires that the user-interaction has ended.
It fires when the alignment-animation finished.

Between both events the scrolling is animated (hopefully) within a fraction of a second.
I like to handle the second event only but I can not see any difference between those two event-objects.
How to do differ programmatically between those two events?

Have a look! The console window is somehow only around as big as the div.

@deEr. Yes, sad integration. However, I think the problem can be understood.

The problem yes. But to figure out how to differ programmatically the console output is needed.

@deEr. Everybody could press F12 and use the browser's console.

. Nice one...

For me at F12 it only shows 1 event. And when looking at the snippet console there the same?

@deEr. Very interresting. I am using firefox, what are you using?

Chrome. Edge the same.

@deEr. Thanks, I removed the browser-tag and added the firefox-tag.
